# export array key and value as variable name and value

Tags: php, arrays

considering this array :

```
$segments = array(
    "key1"    =>"111",
    "key2"    =>"222",
    "key3"    =>"333",
    "key4"    =>"444"
);
```

I want to have these:

`$key1` has the value of  `"111";`

`$key2` has the value of  `"222";`

`$key3` has the value of  `"333";`

`$key4` has the value of  `"444";`

What can I do ?

Answer (score 16):

PHP has a built-in function that does exactly this:

```
extract($segments);
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.extract.php

Comment: thank you :) my mind is becoming crazy, `extract` and not `export`, right it down man!!! LOL

Answer (score 8):

use

```
extract($segments)
```

References:

- [extract](http://www.php.net/extract) Extract the keys of an hash array into the corresponding variables
- [compact](http://www.php.net/compact) Does the reverse thing